# Going up a directory in relative paths within models

Tags: data-binding, combobox, sapui5, relative-path

For an oData Model, I need to go up a directory.

This is an approximation of the structure:

EditModel:

```
-->Entity A
    -->Entity B
    -->Entity C
```

I need a ComboBox inside the Entity B Table that pulls from the Entity C table. I can't do an absolute path, and binding shared comboboxes is painful.

So in the Path for ComboBox items, I need a relative path that looks like:

> path = editModel>../C

('..' as in 'cd ..' - for up directory)

Essentially, I need to be able to back out one directory, to view the other. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A backward property doesn't exist in OData, but you could leverage (forward) navigation properties as well, e.g.:

```
-->Supplier A
    --> Product A
    --> Product B
```

In this case, you would see all products of supplier A by querying: `Suppliers('A')/Products`

If the service is configured nicely, the opposite would work as well:

```
--> Product A
    --> Supplier A
--> Product B
    --> Supplier A
```

To find out which supplier supplies Product A, you could then query: `/Product('A')/Supplier`.

If the `Product` entity doesn't have a navigation property `Supplier`, you may need to talk to your ABAP/Gateway folks to see if it's possible to get this implemented.